# Nexus does not download from other than standard proxy repositories

Tags: maven, nexus

We have a nexus repository manager set up. We are running version 1.9.3.2 and I am not able to upgrade at the moment.

The problem I have is that nexus works fine with the standard proxy repositories that come out of the box when nexus is installed. But when I add new repositories such as JBoss, artifacts are not downloaded from them. If i click JBoss in the user inteface I can check the tab "Browse Remote" and see that the artifacts I want really are there. But when I click "Browse Local" the only thing I see is the file `archetype-catalog.xml`.

What happends is this:

1. I add a dependency to my project
2. It is not found beacause it does not exist in the maven central repo
3. I add a proxy repo in nexus which does contain the artifact I want.
4. I try to build my project again but the artifact is still not found.

I realize that there can be caching issues here but I have run maven forcing updates (-U parameter), deleted cache files from my local repo, cleared cache in nexus, rebuild metadata, all I can think of and the artifacts are still not found.

Does anyonw know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solutions:

1. Enable (set True) `Download Remote Indexes` in the proxy repository configuration.
2. Add the proxy repository to the Public Repositories group.